# What happens after David opens his eyes?

Tags: plot-explanation, vanilla-sky

In the movie Vanilla Sky, David is cryopreservation/frozen after his death by Life Extension and he's seen to have lucid dreams. In the end when the tech support asks him if he wants to be put back on the modified cryopreservation program or if he wants to live the real life, David chooses the latter. The tech support also mentions that David has been frozen for 150yrs.

Considering he was 30-40yrs old when he committed suicide, he would be a whole of 180-190yrs old when he wakes up to 'Open your Eyes' phrase. What seemingly happens to him then? Is his physical and mental age altered too or is it going to be the same (preserved) when he chose to be frozen?

Answer (score 7):

David is in a state of suspended animation; aka cryogenically frozen. Because of this, his body has not aged during this time. While it never directly says this, the movie implies it pretty strongly. Here's the dialog from near the end:

> VENTURA:
>   It is now your moment of choice.
>   You can return to your Lucid
>   Dream, and live a beautiful life
>   with Sofia, or whomever you
>   wish... or you can choose the
>   world out there.
>
> DAVID:
>   The world out. there. And you can
>   bring me back, just. like Benny the
>   Dog.
>
> VENTURA:
>   Yes. Just like Benny the Dog.
>   Your face and body can now be
>   fixed, of course.

Ventura tells David that his "body can now be fixed". This means that in the future, they have the medical technology available to cure the overdose that killed him; and this wouldn't make any sense to say if he would then simply die of old age anyway.

What happens to David after he wakes up though would be complete speculation. We do know that the life as he knew it is completely over; none of his former friends or family would still be alive. He would be starting over in what's a brand new world to him.